# Python - Selenium WebDriverWait does not work without breakpoint

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-3.7, webdriverwait

I'm trying to collect some data from

```
https://www.91mobiles.com/phonefinder.php
```

I have to wait for an ajax call in order to get the 'next' button, but WebDriverWait seems ignored (does not get hit) without a breakpoint.
It used to work 2 weeks back then, but now it doesn't.

- I thought it is the web driver -> change to chrome instead of firefox but result is the same
- Update every packages to latest -> same
- Tried to use C# with same implementation -> works, I don't know why
  => wrap it up, maybe the problem is not at their website

C# syntax:

```
Driver.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' });");

Wait.Until(s => s.FindElement(By.CssSelector('div#finder_pagination>div.listing-btns>div.listing-btns4>span')));

Driver.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });");
// Work as expected
...
```

Python syntax:

```
# Scroll to bottom for AJAX loading
self.browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });')

# timeout is 30 seconds, execution will be delayed until the 'NEXT' button found
self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#finder_pagination>div.listing-btns>div.listing-btns4>span')))

# after that, scroll back to top
self.browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });')
# The web does not wait, it scroll right away and execute the next code
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine on my end, but here where I believe might cause the issue.
In your `wait.until()` you are using `presence_of_element_located`.

As you stated it was working before and does not work anymore. My guess is that the element is found but was not fully loaded then you called to scroll on top which did not make the element appear.

Another method of EC is `visibility_of_element_located`. This one will use same logic as the presence.. but will only return the element once it is allow visible using

```
is_disaplayed()
```

Change your code to use this method instead:

```
driver.get('https://www.91mobiles.com/phonefinder.php')
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# timeout is 30 seconds, execution will be delayed until the 'NEXT' button found
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#finder_pagination .listing-btns4')))

# after that, scroll back to top
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });')
```

Your css_selector was working but as you can see I have changed it for a simpler and more readable one.

Comment: Not sure this is what I'm looking for or not since replacing my code by yours does not solve my problem. After 2hrs rewrite everything with your suggestion it works now. Arghhh f*k my brain, I don't even know why.Upvoted however my rep is < 5. Thanks

Comment: Confusing?!?! It works or not? Can you provide more details on the end goal of this?